# Not able to find SVG Element using Python Selenium Webdriver

Tags: svg, selenium-webdriver

I am trying  to locate rect id values in the below XML code , but getting it as Empty List. Any help on this much appreciated!!!!!

```
<object id="nodia"
 < svg id="svg2"  xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  < g id="layer1>
   <image id="image3022"></image>
   <rect id="rect8696"></rect>
   <rect id="rect8996-6" ></rect>
  </g>
 </svg>
</object>
```

Tried all the below Possibilties in both chrome and Firefox:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//object[@id='nodia']") -> worked
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg']") -> Returns an Empty List
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[local-name()= 'svg']") ->Returns a
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//object[@id='nodia']/svg") -> Returns an Empty List

Answer (score 0):

To get the `id` attribute for each `rect` element with an XPath:

```
for e in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("id('svg2')//*[name()='rect']") :
    print e.get_attribute("id")
```

Or with a CSS selector:

```
for e in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#svg2 rect") :
    print e.get_attribute("id")
```

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_xpath("id('svg2')//*[name()='rect']") also just returns an empty list and not the rect id values. Please help on this!